# Entangling the atoms in a molecule

Tags: atomic-physics, quantum-entanglement, molecules

I came across several papers that use entangled states of 2 ions in a trap to perform measurements with a much higher accuracy than classical (non-entanglement) methods. [Here](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.123.203001) is an example of such a paper where they achieve the best measurement to date of an isotope shift. I was wondering if something similar can be done (or has been done) in diatomic molecules. In that case we already have 2 ions close to each other, so I was wondering if there is a way to entangle the 2 constituents atoms such that you gain some further advantage over normal spectroscopy techniques. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The major difference and issue with trying to entangle to ions of a diatomic molecule is that their respective valence electrons are free to move between the diatomic or are already completely localized on one of the atoms. In ion trap experiments each ion has a single valence electron that is manipulated to move between the qubit states or read out the state of the ion. This is not possible to my knowledge with a diatomic as if you attempted to excite the valence electron(s) of the molecule both atoms in the molecule would be affected. I suppose another way of stating this is that the electronic state of the two atoms of a molecule are inherently entangled but manipulating that entanglement for a clock usually requires having a lever to manipulate each atom individually which would be difficult.

On a related note though people have entangled ions with molecular ions and then used quantum logic spectroscopy to read out the state of the molecules, [here](https://www.nature.com/articles/nature16513#:%7E:text=Quantum%20logic%20spectroscopy%20is%20one,a%20co%2Dtrapped%20atomic%20ion.) and some of the best clocks have also used this technique to readout other ions such as Al+ which has a very narrow clock transition [here](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.123.033201). So it could be possible to use molecular ions as a clock in the future in this way.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think that anyone has ever observed entanglement between two electrons within a molecule - that would be quite a difficult task. However, experimentalists have entangled multiple atoms trapped nearby each other (similar to the trapped ion experiments you describe). See https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.12326 for a recent review article.

Entanglement between atoms is a way to improve precision of normal atomic clocks, which is useful for precision measurements like how you describe. See https://news.mit.edu/2020/atomic-clock-time-precise-1216 for an example experiment.